# Graphics of Far Cry 3 not that good after unexpected shutdown

Tags: far-cry-3, graphics-card

First of all, I know this is not a site about hardware problems. But I think if we are gamers, then we probably know something about the hardware. So here is the problem: I was playing Far Cry 3 on my laptop on ultra settings, and it was working smoothly. Now, the laptop's battery just died, and there was an unexpected shutdown. And when I charged it back up, the graphics in ultra settings are laggy, I mean that smoothness is not there now.

What is the problem? I know I would not get good replies, but please help me. Is my graphics card damaged or something? (By the way the laptop runs a NVIDIA GeForce 940m 2gb)

Comment: First you should try lowering the setting and see if the problem persists, if it still has performance problems it could potentially point to a graphics card malfunction. EDIT: Actually, it running smoothly on lower settings can still point to a GPU problem, but it can show, to some degree, how severe the problem is.

Comment: DirectX 11 causes significant drop in performance. Try playing with it; I'd recommend using GeForce Experience, it works well [sometimes] in such situations.  

Also there might be applications in background that cause performance drop, although I have to break it to you that there is no way you can play pretty much any recent AAA game on a laptop on ultra settings (I played FC3 on 675MX on mid to high settings with DirectX 11 off)

Answer (score 1):

No, your GPU is not damaged, it is performing as it should.
It is perfectly normal for a GeForce 940M to be unable to achieve smooth framerates on Far Cry 3 on Ultra settings:

The 940M is [slower than a 650M](http://gpuboss.com/gpus/GeForce-GT-650M-vs-GeForce-940M#performance) and [slightly faster than a 640M](http://gpuboss.com/gpus/GeForce-GT-640M-vs-GeForce-940M#performance).

According to [this Far Cry 3 benchmark](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Far-Cry-3-Benchmarked.86061.0.html), on Ultra settings at 1920x1080, the framerate with the 650M is only 9 FPS (frames per second), which is totally unplayable.
With the "High" preset at 1366x768, both the 640M and 650M get 28 FPS, which is barely playable with VSync off (and assuming the framerate doesn't fluctuate).

---

What is surprising however is that you remember getting a smooth framerate on ultra settings earlier. It could be because:

- it wasn't actually on ultra settings, or
- it was running at a very low resolution, or
- it was a video cutscene

By the way what is the native resolution of your laptop?